# SSH connection with Sourcetree & PHPStorm

Tags: git, ssh, phpstorm

I have a SSH server configured with git and laravel installed.

Laravel works fine, it shows me the home view so that's OK.

The problem is that I want to code laravel in PHPStorm and save the changes in the SSH with VCS through SourceTree.

I've followed the Git offical documentation:

1. Installed Git in the SSH server
2. Configured my identity like this:
   git config --global user.name "Polinicles"
   git config --global user.email sergi.bema@gmail.com
3. I start a git repository on my root directory (/var/www/html) where I also installed the laravel folder:
       git init
4. After, I add all the files typing:
   git add .
5. I've configured the SourceTree like this:
   [Sourcetree1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHYwR.png)
6. I've tried cloning the git repo from my SSH to the git website but it tells me that I've cloned an empty repo.[Putty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alalb.png)

I'm really desesperated, is not the first time I try to set up Git with other tutorials, manuals, etc...With no results. Obviously I can not set up PHPStorm either.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

To work in a local repository and push it to your remote on the server do the following:

- `ssh root@Laravel`
- `git --bare init`
- on your local machine:
- `git init`
- `git remote add origin ssh://root@laravel/var/www/html`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Your commit message"`
- `git push origin master`

Then everytime you need to push changes to your laravel server, commit and push using the last three commands again.

---

Original answer:
It appears you are trying to copy the files from github but your repository on github is empty.

If you want to add the contents of your local folder to your github repository, you will have to do the following:

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "A commit message"`
- `git push origin master`

This will add all the files in the current directory to the local repository and create a commit. Afterwards it will push the commit to github.

Keep in mind that `git clone` is used to "download" from the repository you specify, you will have to use `git push origin master` to upload your repository to github.

Comment: Well, What I want is to work with the laravel files in local (coding it in PHPStorm) and then push that to the SSH repository. Shall I clone then?